# How to crawl Yellowpages with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape yellowpages and having an error which is no attribute response in "crawler name". I'm currently working in linux, ubuntu with python 2.7.3. The code is the following:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class yellowpages(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yellowpages'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.yellowpages.com/whitepages']

def parse(self, response):
  return [FormRequest.from_response(response, headers = None, formdata = {"last name": "lastname person one"}, callback = self.parse_results)]

def parse_results(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    print hxs.select('//h3').extract()
```

edit:

As requested I am putting the output. For some reason, it seems to be outputting the page now. I think it may have been running the code even as I saved it, and I needed to reboot my terminal. Now it seems to be posting out some css.

```
     ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.
  print hxs.select('//h3').extract()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py:106:       ScrapyDeprecationWarning: scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector is deprecated, instantiate scrapy.Selector instead.
  for x in result]
#CSS Output, removed between terminal and stackoverflow to help with formationg
2014-07-06 15:22:16-0400 [yellowpages] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-07-06 15:22:16-0400 [yellowpages] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2382,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 40878,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 6, 19, 22, 16, 316969),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 6, 19, 22, 14, 117396)}
2014-07-06 15:22:16-0400 [yellowpages] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: @KevinLondon It strangely ran better this time where I actually got some css output, so I think I may be having a problem with parsing rather than the actual spider.

Comment: DId you read error message ? `Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.` and `scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector is deprecated`.

Comment: @furas, Yes, I edited it so that there is no error, but I'm having problem getting an output still.

Comment: I tried to connect with `http://www.yellowpages.com/whitepages` in browser but I got `error 403` - maybe server was down.

Comment: @furas, It's working for me. However, I think what it is, is that the spider is using the header form instead of the body.

Comment: So, there are two things that need to be done. the header needs set so that formnumber needs set to 1, and there is a 200 error which means the parser is incorrect.

Comment: I created scrapy spider with your code but again I can access page and I think that this server is very cleaver and it recognized that I used bot/script and now I have no access to server for a time

Comment: I actually just got it working. the 200 is the parser, and first you have to throw the return through the selector, and then use a css parser, and then for each item in the parser you have to print it and then clean it up. I was using scrapy on linux. But it shouldn't be much different other than creating some fields for items.

Answer (score 1):

so originally, I had a problem with yellowpages and data being written to the header form. The easiest way to bypass this is setting form_number to 1. Code is the following:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response, header = None, formnumber = 1, formdata = {"last": "examplename", "state": "examplestate"}, cakkback = self.parse_results)]
```

The next problem was a parsing the best way I found is to pass the response through a selector and then setting the selector(response_ through xpath in the following manner.

```
def parse_results(self, response):
    hxs scrapy.Selector(response)
    phone_numbers = hxs.xpath('//p').extract)
    for item in phone_numbers:
            ............
```

From here, you just remove the text and write it to whatever document you need.